# Query Postgres JSONB with traversal of nested key when first parent key is unknown

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I'm trying to query using JSONB however I have a problem where I don't know what the first key could be.

Ideally I would be able to use a wildcard inside my query.

eg: The following works

```
WHERE json_data #> '{first_key,second_key}' = '"value-of-second-key"'
```

but I may not know the name of the first_key or want to match any of the nested sub keys.
Something like.

```
WHERE json_data #> '{*,second_key}' = '"value-of-second-key"'
```

Would be ideal using a wildcard like '*'

Any advice or approaches to this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use wildcard for `#>` operator, but you can use [`jsonb_each` function to unnest the first level of the JSON](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html):

```
SELECT *
FROM jsonb_each('{"foo": {"second_key": "xxx"}, "bar": {"other_second_key": "xxx"}, "baz": {"second_key": "yyy"}}') AS e(key, value)
WHERE e.value @> '{"second_key": "xxx"}';
```

Result:

```
 key |         value         
-----+-----------------------
 foo | {"second_key": "xxx"}
(1 row)
```

If you just want to search for the row matching it though (and not the exact json element, as above) you can use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT ...
FROM the_table t
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM jsonb_each(t.the_jsonb_column) AS e(key, value)
    WHERE e.value @> '{"second_key": "xxx"}'
)
```

Logically, this approach works fine, but be warned that it can't get advantage of an index as would `e.value @> '{"foo": {"second_key": "xxx"}}'`, so if performance is really a matter, you may want to rethink your schema.